# jquery.timepicker DST issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timezone, dst, timepicker

I am using the jQuery plugin [jquery.timepicker](http://jonthornton.github.com/jquery-timepicker/)

```
var dateObj = new Date("Mon, 05 Nov 2012 06:30:00 -0600");
$('#my_start_time_id').timepicker('setTime', dateObj);
```

But the time set is shifting back by one hour. That is, the time set to `$('#my_start_time_id')` is `5.30am` instead of `6.30am`.

I am seeing this issue after today's DST changes.
Could you please give some hints to fix this issue?

**Note**: I checked the value of 'dateObj' it is `Mon Nov 05 2012 06:30:00 GMT-0600 (CST)`

Comment: You can't easily detect DST (there are some functions and libraries for that though), and the user's computer automatically recalculates the time if DST is on. Probably using Date.UTC then setting the timezone offset might be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to a bug in jquery.timepicker plugin on DST transition day.
Inside this plugin, it uses a variable called '_baseDate' which is set to starting a day.The _baseDate should be adjusted on DST transition day(Like Nov 4th 2012 in US timezones)